# How can I make a function that calculates my grades?

Tags: c, function

When I try to compile **I get this error: conflicting types for 'compute_GPA'.**

*My main function tests compute_GPA and compute_GPA sholuld calculate the average of the grades!*

What have I declared wrong?
**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>   /* for access to the toupper function */

/* Test a function that calculates the average of grades in a char array. main tests the function */

int main(void)
{
    char a[5] = {'A','C','B','C','D'};
    float see = compute_GPA(a, 5);
    printf("largest = %f", see);  
    return 0;
}

float compute_GPA(char grades[], int n)
{
    float sum = 0;
    int i;
    float count = 0;
    /*Iterate over the array of chars */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        count++;
        /*Check what char array contain*/
        char check = grades[i];
        switch(toupper(check)) {
            case 'A': sum += 4; break;
            case 'B': sum += 3; break;
            case 'C': sum += 2; break;
            case 'D': sum += 1; break;
            default:sum += 0; break;
        }
    }
    return sum / count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the function `compute_GPA()` definition above `main()` or

Declare a prototype for it before `main()`:

```
float compute_GPA(char*, int);
```

In pre-C99, the compiler assumes a function would return an `int` if it can't see the declaration. But this implicit declaration conflicts with the actual definition of `compute_GPA()`. But this "implicit int" rule has been removed from C99 and later. Thus your code is invalid in modern C.

Comment: Thanks it helped i forget

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
float compute_GPA(char grades[], int n);
```

Before int main and inside int main write

```
float see;see = compute_GPA(a,5);
```

sometimes initialization and assignment in one line creates problem

Comment: "_sometimes initialization and assignment in one line creates problem_" -- Could you show me those problems?

Comment: @CoolGuy sometimes during complex programming when you initialize & assign in one line gives undefined behavior read this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/75039/why-declare-a-variable-in-one-line-and-assign-to-it-in-the-next

Comment: The link you have doesn't mention UB anywhere. And the OP is using a C99 compiler. So there isn't any difference. I agree that it would reduce confusion, but in this case, it would not.

Comment: @uditr043  Here he is using  C99 so that doesn't make any difference .Please see this link -http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-declarations-initializations/184401377